# SVM classification with always high precision

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, libsvm

I have a binary classification problem and I'm trying to get precision-recall curve for my classifier. I use libsvm with RBF kernel and probability estimate option.

To get the curve I'm changing decision threshold from 0 to 1 with steps of 0.1. But on every run, I get high precision even if recall decreases with increasing threshold. My false positive rate seems always low compared to true positives.

My results are these:

```
Threshold: 0.1
TOTAL TP:393, FP:1, FN: 49
Precision:0.997462, Recall: 0.889140

Threshold: 0.2
TOTAL TP:393, FP:5, FN: 70
Precision:0.987437, Recall: 0.848812

Threshold: 0.3
TOTAL TP:354, FP:4, FN: 78
Precision:0.988827, Recall: 0.819444

Threshold: 0.4
TOTAL TP:377, FP:9, FN: 104
Precision:0.976684, Recall: 0.783784

Threshold: 0.5
TOTAL TP:377, FP:5, FN: 120
Precision:0.986911, Recall: 0.758551

Threshold: 0.6
TOTAL TP:340, FP:4, FN: 144
Precision:0.988372, Recall: 0.702479

Threshold: 0.7
TOTAL TP:316, FP:5, FN: 166
Precision:0.984424, Recall: 0.655602

Threshold: 0.8
TOTAL TP:253, FP:2, FN: 227
Precision:0.992157, Recall: 0.527083

Threshold: 0.9
TOTAL TP:167, FP:2, FN: 354
Precision:0.988166, Recall: 0.320537
```

Does this mean I have a good classifier or I have a fundamental mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons for this could be while training the data you have lot of negative samples than positive ones. Hence, almost all the examples are being classified as negative samples except the few. Hence, you get high precision i.e. less false positives and low recall i.e. more false negatives.

Edit:

Now that we know you have more negative samples than positive ones:

If you look at the results, as and when you increase the threshold the number of False negatives are increasing i.e. your positive samples are classified as negative ones, which is not a good thing. Again, it depends on your problem, some problems will prefer high precision over recall, some will prefer high recall over precision. If you want both precision and recall to be high, you might need to resolve class imbalance, by trying **oversampling** (repeating positive samples so that ratio becomes 1:1) or **undersampling** (taking random negative samples in proportion with positive samples) or something more sophisticated like **SMOTE** algorithm (which adds similar positive samples).

Also, I am sure there must be "**class_weight**" parameter in the classifier, which gives more importance to error in the class where there are less training examples. You might want to try giving more weight to positive class than negative ones.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, my negative samples are much more in number than positive ones (about 4:1 ratio). However by visual inspection, it classifies true positives accurately. How can I further investigate the possible issue you mentioned?

Comment: On update about training sample sizes, can having less positive samples than negative ones cause tests to be classified with high precision whatever threshold we have? The behavior I observe is this, if the classifier decides a sample as positive it is generally true (generally with probability > 0.6, 0.7). There seems like it is working as black and white. There is so narrow grey region which the model classifies as false positive.

Comment: Didn't exactly get what you are trying to say, can you please elaborate?

Comment: I meant, false positive rate is too low. I have false negatives but false positives are always low. If it classifies as positive, it is generally True Positive. This behaviour made me nervous about generality.

Answer (score 0):

Having a **high precision** can be that your data has a *pattern* that your model seems to grasp easily so it's a good classifier.
Maybe your measures are incorrectly computed or the most probable : your model is [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting). That means that your model is not learning but rather memorizing.
This can be produced by testing your model on your training set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In fact I trained the model with a totally different set than that is used for this test results. But in another set my results are not good as this. Therefore even my training set is different, my model may have a bias, I'm not sure about this.