# Stratified sampling for Random forest -Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest

I'm building a random forest classification model with the response variable split being 98%(False)-2%(True). I'm using Scikit Learn's RandomForest classifier for this.

What is the best way to handle this unbalanced data and avoid oversampling?

Comment: I have already answered the question here. Please check. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36255925/2523817

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameter `class_weight` .

Weights associated with classes in the form `{class_label: weight}`

You can give more weight to your small class and find best weight using cross-validation.

For example `class_weight={1: 10, 0:1}`. Gives more weight to class labeled 1.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of sklearn's random forest classifier, you can simply set class_weight="balanced".